# Many-to-many "through" table with multiple rows of identical foreign key pairs only allowed once to be added

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using `mysql` dialect with `sequelize-v6`

I've two tables

```
class Role extends Model {}

Role.init({
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    },
    {
        ...
    });
```

and

```
class Employee extends Model {}
Employee.init({
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,

        },
        ...

    },

    {
        ...
    });
```

and I am connecting them using:

```
class EmployeeRole extends Model {
}

EmployeeRole.init({
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        targetId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: ''
        }
    },
    {
        ...
    });
```

The relations are:

```
RoleModel.belongsToMany(EmployeeModel, {
        as: 'Employees',
        through: EmployeeRoleModel,
        foreignKey: {
            name: 'roleId', allowNull: false
        },
        otherKey: {
            name: 'employeeId',
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
EmployeeModel.belongsToMany(RoleModel, {
        as: 'Roles',
        through: EmployeeRoleModel,
        foreignKey: {
            name: 'employeeId',
            allowNull: false
        },
        otherKey: {
            name: 'roleId',
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
```

The problem is:

> The employee might have the same **roleId** hence same **employeeId** but with different **resourceId**
>   and whenever I am trying to put another entity, it overwrites the previous one

for ex.:

```
{ roleId: 2, employeeId: '#33', resourceId: 'profiles' }
{ roleId: 2, employeeId: '#33', resourceId: 'screenshots' }
```

**Expected output, they get both added to database**

**Actual output, only the last one added and overwrites the previous one**

for implementing the logic:

```
const employeeRole = await RoleModel.findByPk(3);
const promise = await employee.addRole(employeeRole, {through: { targetId: 'whatever' }})
    .then(role=>role)
    .catch(_=>null);

// If there is a previous one it will overwrite
```

### #Edit

I've spent a lot of time searching but got no result.

I've also seen this issue on github which kinda similiar,

[Many-to-many "through"...](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3493)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many ways, and thanks for [ShGKme](https://github.com/ShGKme) for his [comment](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3493#issuecomment-620174749)

I've got it solved by creating two **1:M** relations:

```
EmployeeModel.hasMany(EmployeeRoleModel, {
        as: 'EmployeeRoles',
        foreignKey: {
            name: 'employeeId',
            allowNull: false
        }
    });

RoleModel.hasMany(EmployeeRoleModel, {
        as: 'EmployeeRoles',
        foreignKey: {
            name: 'roleId',
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
```